# Rsync for windows

Tags: windows, rsync

I am trying to get some files from an `rsync` location to my pc, using `cwrsync`. I haven't used `rsync` before. The given `rsync` location has this format rsync://eugene.program.com/singapore (this is just an example to understand the format, it is not real rsync location). The code that I have written gives me errors:

```
@ECHO OFF
REM ---
REM Simple rsync wrapper to mirror UK Dartcom data to the Singapore Dartcom system.
REM ---
:list_sat
REM ECHO ---
REM ECHO Listing remote HRIT directory...
REM rsync rsync://eugene.program.com/singapore/
REM GOTO end
:get_sat
C:
cd \UK\Ingest\Dartcom\RawData
ECHO ---
ECHO Synchronising remote HRIT...
C:\uk\ingest\rsync.exe -auH rsync://eugene.program.com/singapore//*.bz2 c:/UK/Ingest/Dartcom/RawData
:end
ECHO ---
ECHO Done.
REM ---
```

Comment: What is the error you get? Why do you think you get an error?

Comment: If I put -e, It says that the rsync://eugene.program.com/singapore//*.bz2 doen't exist.

Comment: If I don't put -e it says that the source and the destination cannot both be remote